# Technical difference between web garden and web farm?

Tags: .net, iis-7

Need to know the implementation difference between web garden and web form in case of .net application hosting on iis 7.

Can any one provide me a detail information related to the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A web garden setting on IIS7 (covered here [IIS and web garden configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155684/iis-and-web-garden-configuration)) allows IIS to spawn multiple worker processes for an IIS Virtual Directory to scale up when IIS gets multiple simultaneous calls. This simulates the effect of scaling out to a Web Farm (where the Virtual Directory exists on multiple IIS installations on seperate boxes under an NLB).

Why is this important ? If you code your .net IIS application without Web Garden turned on in IIS you wont recognise that you have accidentally coded a "sticky" service with affinity between the client and the web service, typically using caches incorrectly or chaining business calls on the same server generating a unexpected state dependency.

I typically instruct all my teams to develop with Web Garden turned on for their local IIS to make sure they dont stumble into issues that would hurt in a scaled out environment.